# How to add multiple authors and multiple affiliations with Quarto and export it to MS Word?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, docx, quarto

I am looking for a way to produce something like this with Quarto in Rstudio. I would appreciate it if the output can be in `docx` format
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Quarto extension [`authors-block`](https://github.com/kapsner/authors-block) does exactly what you want.

```
---
title: "Authors-block Example"
authors:
  - name: Eric Scott
    affiliations:
      - ref: uf
    corresponding: true
    email: myemail@institute.edu
  - name: Author Two
    affiliations:
      - ref: uf
      - ref: eu
affiliations:
  - id: uf
    name: University of Florida, Gainesville, Florida 32611-0430 USA
  - id: eu
    name: Example University 123 Center Avenue, New York, New York 10027 USA

filters:
  - authors-block

format:
  docx: default
---
```

---

[image: authors-block example output screenshot]

---